# how to access global_options in ruby commander

Tags: ruby, command-line-interface

How do I access the global_options of the ruby gem commander?  I've see examples like

```
global_option('--verbose') { $verbose = true }
...
c.action do |args, options|
  say 'foo' if $verbose
...
```

If I want to check the option outside of the c.action block, how is that done?

Answer (score 0):

As to my knowledge one wouldn't access global_option directly outside the action block.
That's not a problem as there are multiple options to handle global settings, both tied to the block being called by global_option.

**Option 1:**

Set hash/array inside the block.

```
my_options = Hash.new
global_option('--verbose') do |f| 
  my_options['verbose'] = true
end
...
puts "Verbose." if my_options['verbose']
```

**Option 2:**

Do stuff *inside* the block once the option is triggered by the user.

```
global_option('--debug') do |f| 
  MyLogger.level = Logger::DEBUG
end
```